Integrating member invatation to Snapchat through an API
To give you a bit of context, I work for the agency where we have a lot of accounts from snapchat for certain clients. Those accounts are stored in our database whenever a new account was created. In order for us to have access to that account an invatation is sent to us via email to which we click on it and accept it.
I would like to see if anyone knows if this is possible to be done programmatically so we remove this manual step of accepting an invatation in our email?
I am already handling email with my lambda function since we are using AWS, I can access it's content and that link. The only thing is how do I accept invitation? In Snapchat docs there is nothing regarding this so am wondering if there is some kind of workaround?
I could't really do much as that link is just a link that we get in email not an api so I can't make a call with it.

You will have to automate acceptance of the invitation to provide it now, and that is done by the simulation of a click through the code. Due to the fact that this feature is not directly available in the API of Snapchat, one has to deal with a headless browser. Here you can see the guide:
Guide:
Step 1:  Extract the invitation link:

Since you already have a Lambda function for email and extracting an
invitation link, ensure you have stored or passed the URL to the
following step.

Step 2: Use a headless browser like Selenium:

Install Selenium and WebDriver:

pip install selenium


Download the correct WebDriver based on the browser to be used—for instance, ChromeDriver for Chrome.

Step 3: SetUp Selenium in Python

Begin with this Python script. The script below will open up a headless browser, navigate to the invitation link, and then simulate acceptance.

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

# Path to your ChromeDriver
chrome_driver_path = '/path/to/chromedriver'

# Set up headless browser options
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')

# Initialize WebDriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path, 
options=options)

def accept_invitation(invitation_url):
    try:
        # Navigate to the invitation URL
        driver.get(invitation_url)
        time.sleep(3)  # Wait for the page to load

        # Simulate the acceptance process
        # Note: Adjust the following lines according to the actual elements on the Snapchat invitation page
        accept_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(), 'Accept')]")
        accept_button.click()
        time.sleep(2)  # Wait for the action to complete

        print("Invitation accepted successfully!")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
    finally:
        driver.quit()

# Example usage
invitation_url = "https://example.com/invitation-link"  # Replace with the actual invitation link
accept_invitation(invitation_url)

Note:

XPath: Changed is the XPath to the "Accept" button according to the actual structure of the Snapchat invitation page. You can use something like Chrome DevTools to inspect the page and find out the correct XPath.


Headless Mode: Run the browser in headless mode to ensure it has no GUI—a feature quite fitting for server environments.


WebDriver Path: Make sure the variable chrome_driver_path is pointing to the correct path of the ChromeDriver executable.


Ok I will try this and before I begin, is there anyway I can automate this script to run within my AWS service? I know Lambda doesn't support the selenium or headless browser.
